# Getting an error when using req.session.userID

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using req.session.userID variable to set a sessionID for the user.
My code is

On the server side,

```
router.post('/signin', bodyParser.json(),function(req, res){
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('userCollection');
var name = req.body.name;
var password = req.body.password;
name = name.trim();
password = password.trim();

collection.find({"name":name}, {}, function(e1, username){
    if (e1 === null){

        if (username[0].password == password) {
            req.session.userID = username[0]._id;
            var string2 = "before session" + req.session.userID + "after session" + username[0]._id;
            res.send(string2);
        }
        else {
            res.send("Failure!");
        }
    }
});
```

And on the client side

```
router.post('/signin', bodyParser.json(),function(req, res){
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('userCollection');
var name = req.body.name;
var password = req.body.password;
name = name.trim();
password = password.trim();

collection.find({"name":name}, {}, function(e1, username){
    if (e1 === null){

        if (username[0].password == password) {
            req.session.userID = username[0]._id;
            var string2 = "before session" + req.session.userID + "after session" + username[0]._id;
            res.send(string2);
        }
        else {
            res.send("Failure!");
        }
    }
});
```

I have also set a secret token for in my app.js as advised in some other answers, but still whenever I user req.session.userID it gives me an error.

The moment I remove req.session.userID and just send a normal statement back it works. Can anyone tell me what could be the possible reason for this.

My app.js looks something like this...

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret token'
}))
```

I have even installed express-session. Should I be doing something else too?
Full app.js code,

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');


var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/learnproject1');

var logger = require('morgan');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/myroutes.js');
//var userRouter = require('.')

var app = express();



// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);
//app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret token'
}))
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you post your full code with app.js

Comment: @Dipakchavda I have posted the full app.js code.

Comment: You posted the same code for server side and client side. What are you using at client side? Angular, React or express templating?